# Magento 2.1 EE Show minicart on mouse hover instead of onclick

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to develope minicart should open onhover of it instead of onclick in magento 2.1 EE help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\minicart.phtml
```

use **"triggerEvent" : "hover"**

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "triggerEvent" : "hover",
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": true,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

and need to overright **lib\web\mage\dropdown.js** , remove below code : Line 67

```
else {
    _self.close(event);
}
```

Comment: HI, its not working, i have overrided minicart.phtml file in my theme its not working , throwing error as Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: Can you checked with dong on core file chang?

Comment: please share screen short of error.

Comment: No , i have overrided core files in to my theme, while mouse over on minicart icon nothing is happening, i checked in console its throwing this error "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function"

Comment: Change on Core file and check it, without override

Comment: thank you , its working, but while mouse out from minicart icon , its not closing, when i click on somewhere else outside then its closing.

Comment: you need to overright `lib\web\mage\dropdown.js` as well as

Answer (score 0):

**use "triggerEvent" : "hover"**

**"closeOnMouseLeave": true,**

and remove **"timeout": "2000",**

My code is

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
         data-role="dropdownDialog"
         data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
            "triggerEvent" : "hover",
            "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
            "triggerTarget":".showcart",
            "closeOnMouseLeave": true,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "triggerClass":"active",
            "parentClass":"active",
            "buttons":[]}}'>
        <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
    </div>
```